# What prevents you from installing the pyglut module on Windows 10?

Tags: python, glut

I'm trying to install the pyglut module for rendering an icosahedron using the OpenGL module. But the installation does not work.

My Python version is 3.7.6, pip has version 23.0.1.Computer name: DESKTOP-EOVV49U

Error traceback:

```
Collecting pyglut
  Using cached pyglut-1.0.0.zip (603 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\zlatt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qnyt0xzm\pyglut_720181f5b6054599aa3fd05a5dcd443d\setup.py", line 28, in <module>
          long_description = file.read()
        File "c:\Users\zlatt\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1544: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Presumably, the problem is in the encoding. `setup.py` tried to open a file with the encoding **cp1251**, and that in a different encoding. Most likely, the problem is in `setup.py` - if the encoding is not specified in `open`, then the system encoding is used, i.e. **cp1251**, and not **utf-8**.

How to get the module installed?